# How to sort twitter tweets with java

Tags: java, twitter

I have this code:

```
for (Status tweet : tweets) {
    y++;
    users.add(new twitterTweets(tweet.getUser().getScreenName(), tweet.getText(), tweet.getCreatedAt()));
    System.out.println(y + ": - " + "@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName()
            + " - " + tweet.getText() + " - " + tweet.getCreatedAt());
    i++;
}

Collections.sort(users, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

int a= 0;
for(String temp : users) {
    a++;
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

I want to print out tweets, which are sorted by date (ascending, descending order and the sort is CASE_INSENSITIVE) and I also want to print out tweets sorted by screenname and text. I know that I can use `Collections.sort`, but this does not solve my problem, because when I add screennames in an `ArrayList`, I can only sort screennames and when I want to print out the tweets sorted by screenname, it will give me wrong answer, because the rest of the tweet (text and date) are not sorted with screenname.

How do I sort tweets by

- ScreenName
- Date
- and Text

(both ascending and descending) and print out sorted tweets with correct author, date and text is basically what I am asking?

Comment: Pass comparator into Collections.sort method.

Comment: Can you give me an example, of how to use this Map? Never heard of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a `Comparator` as second parameter to `Collections.sort()`.

**Example:**
You have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {return this.firstName;}  
    public String getLastName()  {return this.lastName;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Now you can sort a `Collection` of `Person` like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Albert", "Einstein"));
        persons.add(new Person("James", "Bond"));

        // sort by lastname, ascending
        Collections.sort(persons, (p1, p2) -> p1.getLastName().toUpper().compareTo(p2.getLastName().toUpper()));        
        persons.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
James Bond
Albert Einstein
```

For other sort orders, use other fields:

```
// firstname, ascending
(p1, p2) -> p1.getFirstName().toUpper().compareTo(p2.getFirstName().toUpper());
//             ^ here is now getFirstName()
```

or for opposing order, switch the objects:

```
// lastname, descending
(p1, p2) -> p2.getLastName().toUpper().compareTo(p1.getLastName().toUpper());
//          ^ here is now p2           ^ here is now p1

// firstname, descending
(p1, p2) -> p2.getFirstName().toUpper().compareTo(p1.getFirstName().toUpper());
//          ^ here is now p2            ^ here is now p1
```

Comment: users.add(new twitterTweets(tweet.getUser().getScreenName(), tweet.getText(), tweet.getCreatedAt()));

This gives me error: 

No enclosing instance of type twitter is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type twitter (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of twitter).

Comment: persons.add(new Person("Albert", "Einstein"));

I changed persons to users and instead of "Alber", "Einstein" I tried to get twitter screenname text and date.

Comment: @Martin The error message `No enclosing instance of type twitter is accessible...` gives all needed information. Maybe you can show an excerpt or the whole twitter class? Edit your Question please.

Comment: Got it working, had to add static reference to my class. Thank you. Now only one problem, that I want to make the sorting to CASE_INSENSITIVE. Where should I add it?

Comment: @Martin Case insensitive can be achieved by comparing the results of `String.toUpper()` of both values (so any case information is lost and only the "value" of the latter is of importance). `"albert".toUpper().compareTo("james".toUpper());` I editet my answer to match this criterion

Answer (score 0):

## Another Example

The [accepted answer by ifLoop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26378291/642706) is correct, complete, and excellent. I just happen to have this complete single-file example showing the use of a Comparator for sorting by date-time, so I thought I would post it as well.

## Joda-Time

I added the used of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) because `java.util.Date` can be so troublesome. I suggest avoiding the .Date/.Calendar classes in favor of Joda-Time or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time). But that is neither here nor there. This example shows both .Date and DateTime.

The default String output by Joda-Time is in standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. This format is much more useful that the output generated by java.util.Date’s `toString` awful format with the JVM’s current default time zone confusingly applied.

```
package com.example.jodatimeexperiment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class Tweet
{

    public String name;
    public Date date;
    public DateTime dateTime;

    public Tweet( String name , DateTime dateTime )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.date = this.dateTime.toDate();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Tweet{" + "dateTime=" + dateTime + ", date=" + date + ", name=" + name + '}' + "\n";
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<Tweet> list = new ArrayList<Tweet>( 4 );
        list.add( new Tweet( "Bob" , DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ) ) );
        list.add( new Tweet( "Pierre" , DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ).plusDays( 5 ) ) );
        list.add( new Tweet( "Sanjay" , DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ).withYear( 1999 ) ) );
        list.add( new Tweet( "Susan" , DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ).minusDays( 4 ) ) );

        System.out.println( "Unsorted:\n" + list.toString() );

        Collections.sort( list , new DateAscendingComparator() );
        System.out.println( "Sorted By Date Ascending:\n" + list.toString() );

        Collections.sort( list , new DateTimeAscendingComparator() );
        System.out.println( "Sorted By DateTime Ascending:\n" + list.toString() );

        Collections.sort( list , new DateTimeDescendingComparator() );
        System.out.println( "Sorted By DateTime Descending:\n" + list.toString() );
    }

}

class DateAscendingComparator implements Comparator<Tweet>
{

    @Override
    public int compare( Tweet o1 , Tweet o2 )
    {
        return o1.date.compareTo( o2.date );
    }
}

class DateTimeAscendingComparator implements Comparator<Tweet>
{

    @Override
    public int compare( Tweet o1 , Tweet o2 )
    {
        return o1.dateTime.compareTo( o2.dateTime );
    }
}

class DateTimeDescendingComparator implements Comparator<Tweet>
{

    @Override
    public int compare( Tweet o1 , Tweet o2 )
    {
        return o2.dateTime.compareTo( o1.dateTime ); // Reversed order for descending.
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Unsorted:
[Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-21T19:00:21.224Z, date=Tue Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Bob}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-26T19:00:21.257Z, date=Sun Oct 26 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Pierre}
, Tweet{dateTime=1999-10-21T19:00:21.257Z, date=Thu Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 1999, name=Sanjay}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-17T19:00:21.257Z, date=Fri Oct 17 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Susan}
]
Sorted By Date Ascending:
[Tweet{dateTime=1999-10-21T19:00:21.257Z, date=Thu Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 1999, name=Sanjay}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-17T19:00:21.257Z, date=Fri Oct 17 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Susan}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-21T19:00:21.224Z, date=Tue Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Bob}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-26T19:00:21.257Z, date=Sun Oct 26 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Pierre}
]
Sorted By DateTime Ascending:
[Tweet{dateTime=1999-10-21T19:00:21.257Z, date=Thu Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 1999, name=Sanjay}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-17T19:00:21.257Z, date=Fri Oct 17 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Susan}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-21T19:00:21.224Z, date=Tue Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Bob}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-26T19:00:21.257Z, date=Sun Oct 26 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Pierre}
]
Sorted By DateTime Descending:
[Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-26T19:00:21.257Z, date=Sun Oct 26 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Pierre}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-21T19:00:21.224Z, date=Tue Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Bob}
, Tweet{dateTime=2014-10-17T19:00:21.257Z, date=Fri Oct 17 12:00:21 PDT 2014, name=Susan}
, Tweet{dateTime=1999-10-21T19:00:21.257Z, date=Thu Oct 21 12:00:21 PDT 1999, name=Sanjay}
]
```